# Does the following improper integral converge? $\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-x^3}(1+\sin(x^2)) \, dx$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

How can I prove using the Direct Comparison Test that $\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-x^3}(1+\sin(x^2)) \, dx$ does or does not converge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ |\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2}e^{-x^{3}}(1+sin(x^{2}))dx| \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} |x^{2}e^{-x^{3}}(1+sin(x^{2}))|dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{2}e^{-x^{3}}|(1+sin(x^{2}))|dx \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{2}e^{-x^{3}} (2)dx$

The first inequality follows from $|\int f| \leq \int |f|$. The second inequality follows since $|1+sin(x^2)| \leq |1| + |\sin (x^2)| \leq 1 + 1 = 2$ and the integrand is non-negative.

[The absolute value bars are never necessary in this, since all the integrands are non-negative (and thus are their integrals), but it looks a bit cleaner with them.]

Now, does the last integral converge? (Hint: $u$-substitute $u=x^3$).

Comment: Holy Remote Control Robot, Batman! It makes sense now. Thanks.